# Matplotlib patches contains_point() returns inconsistent results

Tags: python, matplotlib

Why does changing the plotting parameters of `matplotlib.patches` `contains_point()` change the value to be nonsensical? For example:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
print(mpatches.Circle((0,0), radius=1, ec='r').contains_point((0,1.5)))
print(mpatches.Circle((0,0), radius=1).contains_point((0,1.5)))
```

returns `True` for the first line, and `False` for the second - when obviously a unit circle centered at `(0,0)` does not contain `(0, 1.5)`.

Comment: What I've found: the path of the two circles are the same, i.e. `circle.get_path() == circle_red.get_path()` returns `True`. The `ec` parameter seems to add a 0.5 border to the circle, i.e the poin `(0, 1.6)` retrurns `False` also in the first print. When the first circle is plotted and checked for the point `(0, 1.5)` after the appropriate transform, it returns `False` correctly. So my advice is to set the edgecolor only immediately before the  plot through `set_edgecolor` and check for the points before the plot only on pure figures without plotting params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `contains_point` function you could specify a `radius` parameter so that all points enclosed between the borders of the patch and half the radius specified are also considered in the area. When you specify an `edgecolor` a default `linewidth` is set to 1 and this is going to modify the `radius` parameter in the `contains_point` function. In the [source code](https://matplotlib.org/stable/_modules/matplotlib/patches.html#Patch.contains_point) of this function in fact you can see that there's a call to a `_process_radius` function that modify the `radius` parameter of `contains_point` to linewidth. This behaviour is documented in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path.contains_point) of the `contains_point` function of the general path object:

> The path is extended tangentially by radius/2; i.e. if you would draw the path with a linewidth of radius, all points on the line would still be considered to be contained in the area. Conversely, negative values shrink the area: Points on the imaginary line will be considered outside the area.

From this we can understand the behaviour you are experimenting. To solve you can:

1. `set_edgecolor` after checked for points
2. always specify `radius=0` in the `contains_point` function

```
###### Solution 1 ######
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

circle_ec = mpatches.Circle((0,0), radius=1)
circle = mpatches.Circle((0,0), radius=1)
point = (0,1.5)
print(circle_ec.contains_point(point, radius = 0))         # prints False
print(circle.contains_point(point))                        # prints False
circle_ec.set_edgecolor('r')

###### Solution 2 #######
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

circle_ec = mpatches.Circle((0,0), radius=1, ec='r')
circle = mpatches.Circle((0,0), radius=1)
point = (0,1.5)
print(circle_ec.contains_point(point, radius = 0))         # prints False
print(circle.contains_point(point))                        # prints False
```

Anyway I think that is an unwanted behaviour since `linewidth` is specified in points and not in data coords. Opened an issue [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/19807).